# A simple question about time() function in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

when I print $var , I get the current time continuously .
but I want  to know the code that save the time as a stable variable  "does not increase over the time"

```
$var = time() ;
echo $var ;
```

Comment: Unclear.  Do you want to store it within the scope of an executed script? (use a variable) store it within the scope of a user's session? (use `$_SESSION`) store it in your database? We don't know what you want.  I have a feeling that you haven't researched long enough before asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run this script it will return the current time. this is how the `time()` function works.

You need to store it in someplace to retrieve the same time.